# How can I save the contents of a JTable to a file and then load them back when needed?

Tags: java, swing, file, jtable, save

I'm sorry it's my first time posting here and I am really, really bad at java.

I have a `JTable` in one of my panels and what I need to do is save the contents to a file. When a certain string is entered into a `JTextfield`, the file loads and populates the `JTable`.

I have no clue where to start and I've searched youtube for help and I was sore out of luck. Help me please?

Comment: from where you are populating the data  into the JTable ?

Comment: I am using the DefaultTableModel to add rows and columns.

Comment: Also consider serializing the JTable, I believe that would work.

Comment: @Aaron This does work, but as soon as he changes his code even once, the serialization key changes and all old versions become completely incompatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public Object[][] getTableData (JTable table) {
       (DefaultTableModel) dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
           int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
           Object[][] tableData = new Object[nRow][nCol];
           for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)
               for (int j = 0 ; j < nCol ; j++)
                   tableData[i][j] = dtm.getValueAt(i,j);
           return tableData;
       }
```

You can store the values in the Jtable as an array,

After that write this to the file ...

```
    public void writeToFile()
      {
      try{
      FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
      BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
      for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            out.write(array[i].getBytes());
      }
      out.close();
      }catch (Exception e){
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
```

Comment: Thanks that makes it a little more clear but the part where I'm having trouble is actually writing the array to a file.

Comment: whats the problem you are facing ?

Comment: I don't know how to code to write the array to a file.

Comment: I have edited the answer... let me know if there are any other issues...

If not, mark it as the answer...

Comment: @SrinivasB: `writeToFile()` doesn't compile. How does `array` relate to `tableData`? How should Jay Lee reconstruct the `TableModel` from `out.txt`?